# findById returns null even though record exists (after Spring Boot upgrade)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, amazon-aurora

Doesn't occur locally, only in a Staging Environment, so far.
The issue is inconsistent - sometimes it fails to find the record a few times and then succeeds, without any change to the data.
Sometimes it succeeds on the first try.

Context:

Microservice runs new account setup against API:

- Simple CRUD API
- API request creates customer, returns Customer.
- Immediate next API request creates User on that Customer, using that CustomerId.
- No stack trace as we throw an exception if the Customer is not found

The lookup, using that CustomerId is now failing to find the Customer / instantiate the entity, after upgrading from Spring Boot 1 to 2:

Debug output: logging shows the correct CustomerId being used in the findById request. Used the sql generated by setting hibernate to log the sql.

Service:

```
override fun createUser(name: String, customerId: String): User {
   log.debug("Creating user: $name for customerId: $customerId")
   val customer = customerRepository.findById(customerId).orElse(null)
   if (customer == null) {
     log.error("Unable to create user: $name for customerId: $customerId")
     throw NotFoundException(Message.CUSTOMER_NOT_FOUND)
   }
   // createUser (never reached)
}
```

Logs:

```
Creating user: ZeouterTestingUser for customerId: 1234abc5-fee4-46b9-81f4-6f5df5cc4cc3
Hibernate: 
    select
        customer0_.id as id1_10_0_,
        customer0_.created_by_id as created_2_10_0_,
        customer0_.created_date as created_3_10_0_,
        customer0_.modified_by_id as modified4_10_0_,
        customer0_.modified_date as modified5_10_0_,
        customer0_.internal as internal6_10_0_,
        customer0_.name as name7_10_0_,
        customer0_.source as source8_10_0_,
        customer0_.status as status9_10_0_,
        customer0_.terms_acceptance_date as terms_a10_10_0_,
        customer0_.trial_expiry_date as trial_e11_10_0_ 
    from
        customer customer0_ 
    where
        customer0_.id=?
```

Customer Definition:

```
@Entity
class Customer(@Column(nullable = false) var name: String) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    var id: String = ""

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var status: CustomerStatus = CustomerStatus.ACTIVE

    @Column
    var internal: Boolean = false

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var source: CustomerSource = CustomerSource.ADMIN

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    var trialExpiryDate: Date? = null

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    var termsAcceptanceDate: Date? = null

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = User::class)
    lateinit var users: List<User>

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    var createdDate: Date? = null

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    var modifiedDate: Date? = null

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by_id")
    var createdBy: String? = null

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "modified_by_id")
    var modifiedBy: String? = null

}
```

Customer Repository:

```
interface CustomerRepository : CrudRepository<Customer, String> {
}
```

Database record:

```
id 1234abc5-fee4-46b9-81f4-6f5df5cc4cc3
created_by_id NULL
created_date 2021-12-14 10:33:43.0
modified_by_id NULL 
modified_date 2021-12-14 10:33:43.0
internal 0 
name ZeouterTesting
source SELFSERVICE
status ACTIVE
terms_acceptance_date 2021-12-14 10:33:43.0
trial_expiry_date 2021-12-28 10:33:43.0
```

- Database: Aurora
- DB Driver: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver (2.7.4)
- Framework: Spring Boot 2.1.18 w/ Spring Data JPA

Note - other parts of the API do execute that line successfully, loading the Customer record correctly.

Comment: Stack trace? Error message? Debug output? Sufficient code context? How do you know `customerId` has the correct value?

Comment: @JimGarrison 
Stack trace: No stack trace, we throw an exception if the record is null.
Debug output: logging shows the correct CustomerId being used in the findById request. Used the sql generated by setting hibernate to log the sql.
Code context: It's a fairly simple CRUD API, will add repository details.
Correct value: The above logging, querying the db manually returns the record.

Comment: For future reference, all that info needs to be in the original question.  Please [edit] the question and add it there.

Comment: @JimGarrison gotcha, thanks, have updated my question

Comment: Spring JDBC has A LOT of debugging output you can enable.  Have you investigated that?

Comment: "Doesn't occur locally, only in a Staging Environment." some forgotten/abandoned data source (config)!?

Comment: JimGarrison - will try turn on more of them, thanks
xerx593 - perhaps, but I cannot see any difference so far
jannis - fixed

Comment: An update to this - the behaviour is inconsistent, sometimes it fails a few times and then succeeds, without any change to the data? Sometimes it succeeds on the first try.

Comment: Sounds to me like a session is either not flushing or getting results from cache. Probably the first one, since null values shouldn't get cached, I think. How are your transactions scoped?

Comment: @JensSchauder The service methods saving the new entities are annotated with (at)Transactional, left to the default Propagation.Required, so I believe tied to each rest request. 
For the customer saving (the first entity that it can struggle to find subsequently), I tried both .save & .saveAndFlush (jpaRepository), with the issue persisting.

Comment: Can you verify from logs that the writing transaction commits and the reading transaction actually accesses the database?

Comment: @GavinFitzgerald Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing what could be this exact issue, and this is the first report of anything close to it that I've found after a lot of searching.

Comment: @J.Marciano No, I did not, I built a work around instead [merging dependent api requests into one call instead of two]

Comment: @GavinFitzgerald Well that's unfortunate news for us, I suppose. But the response was appreciated!